# Does PPP do broadcasting?

Tags: networking, protocol-theory, layer2, ppp

Let's consider the scenario below:

Router 1 <---> Router 2 <---> Router 3

Routers 1 and 3 establish a link with router 2, then will Router 2 broadcast to the interface connected to routers 1 and 3 ?, Considering there is no addressing mechanism on PPP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's PPP, there's no "broadcast" per-se... PPP is all unicast between two interface endpoints.